# Is there a way to have an array be passed through a for loop and then increase its count?

Tags: arrays, c

I have the following code and want every element in the array to be passed through a for loop. I then want every passing of the element to increase count when there is an identical value. In the end, i would like to create a chart with every respective value having a frequency of occurrences.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    void show_frequency_chart(int arr[], int n);
    
    int main()
    {
       int test_scores[] = { 90,85,100,50,50,85,60,70,55,55,80,95,70,60,95,80,100,75,70,95,90,90,70,95,50,65,85,95,100,65 };
       int n = sizeof(test_scores) / sizeof(int);
        
       show_frequency_chart(test_scores, n);
    }
    
    
void show_frequency_chart(int arr[], int n)
{
    
   static int scores[256];
    int j, i;
    
    for (i = arr[i]; i < arr[-1]; i++)
    {
        if (scores[j] == arr[i])
        {
            scores[j] = scores[j] + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("score\t\tfrequency\n");
    printf("======\t\t=========\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if(scores[j] != 0)
        {

        printf("%3d\t\t%5d\n", arr[i], scores[j]);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are the range of possible values  integers [0...100] or something  else?

Comment: What value do you expect to find at `arr[-1]`?

Comment: For test_scores[ ] yes values of integers [0...100]

Comment: arr[-1] is the last element in the array, so 65.

Comment: In C, `arr[-1]` ***is not*** the last element of the array.  In your particular case, it is nonsense.  In some other cases, it might represent an element preceding `arr[0]`.

Comment: Josh McCloud, `arr[n-1]` is the last element in the array.  `arr[-1]` attempts to access `arr[]` outside its range of [0....n-1].

Comment: But that's moot, because it doesn't make sense for `show_frequency_chart()` to loop over a range defined by the *values* of the input array in the first place.  It should be looping over the valid *indexes* into the array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to do a frequency vector?
If that is true, there are more ways, and here is a simple one:

You have an array of items that are smaller than 100 so you can create a new array of 101 elements ( 0 - 100 ), initialize it with the value 0, and while looping through your own array, you will say something like: `new_array[my_array[i]]++`, thus increasing the element on that position by 1.

In the end, you can print all values that are different from 0 (meaning they are found at least once in your own array).

Answer (score 0):

To create a frequency chart, you want to loop over all the elements of the input array, and tally each in the appropriate frequency bin.  You are using a separate bin for each possible score, which makes things pretty easy.  Given

```
#define MAX_SCORE 100

// ...
void show_frequency_chart(int arr[], int n) {
    int scores[MAX_SCORE + 1] = { 0 }; // static would be a poor choice here
```

... you want something along these lines:

```
    // loop over all elements
    for (int i = 0; i < n i++) {
        // increment the count for score arr[i]
        int the_score = arr[i];
        // ... your code here ...
    }
```

Comment: Are you introducing a new variable within a for loop (the_score)?

Comment: @JoshMcCloud, yes, for illustrative purposes.  That is not an essential component of a solution.